# Создание объектов на форме в цикле

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Есть tabControl, на нем мне нужно в цикле создать несколько tabPage:

```
int t = 0;
TabPage[] tabDia = new TabPage[5];

while (t < 5)
{
    tabDia[t] = new TabPage();
    DiaTabControl.Controls.Add(tabDia[t]);
    t++;
}
```

Вот если мне надо определенное кол-во `tabPage[5]` создать, то все ок, а если я не знаю, сколько именно мне нужно? Т.е. пока у меня while работает, я создаю вкладки в определенных итерациях.

Что мне написать вот здесь:

```
TabPage[] tabDia = new TabPage[5];
```

**upd:** что означает это: [5]? почему, я могу создать и 6 и 7 при такой записи?
**upd:** в новом проекте все отработало корректно, лишний вкладки не создавались!

Comment: @namak7, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: да нажимал, он вроде даже отображается в редакторе норм, а при сохранении так получается, сейчас, еще раз попробую

Comment: с горем пополам получилось...почему чтобы отформатить код его нужно перенести на 1 строку ниже предыдущего текста? т.е. текст; код - не срабатывает, а текст;пустая строка;код - срабатывает

Comment: Простите, вы читали хоть какую-нибудь книгу по языку? Это базовый синтаксис, основы основ.

Comment: @VladD, понять я хотел, почему указывая new TabPage[5], у меня в цикле while(t<10) создавалось все 10 вкладок, а не что такое [5]..
создал новый проект, потестил, теперь все ок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция, создающая вкладки:

```
void GenerateTabs(int count,TabControl tc)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < count)
            {
                TabPage tp = new TabPage("Tab_"+i.ToString());
                tp.Name = "Tab_"+i.ToString();
                tp.Parent = tc;
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Использовать так:

```
GenerateTabs(5,tabControl1); //tabControl1 это родительский TabControl
```

Или опишите вопрос подробнее.

Comment: надеюсь доступно?

Comment: @cyberdream, ваша запись более оптимальная, спасибо!